Input Number Format
I am working in LwC, and when I enter a value in the input box say 123456789 then when I leave it, it automatically turns to 123,456,789 which is I know an default behavior. But I don't want in that format. How shall I fix that? One solution could be that just change the type to "text", but that will allow the user to enter other than numbers as well which we don't want. Any help could be helpful.
<div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
     <lightning-input class="projectcode" type="number" name="inputprojectcode" label="Project Code" placeholder="Project Code" maxlength="9" 
     onchange={handlepaymentType} value={projectCodeNumber} ></lightning-input>
</div>

